# Libraries that parse code written in C and provide an API

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction

I am implementing a proof of concept application for source-to-source transformation and need a C-parser with an API for manipulating/traversing the C-syntax tree (AST).

I have tried to use `clang` but I ran into various problems, like not being able to compile the tutorials using `libclang`, wrong architecture etc. Since this is a proof of concept application, I will defer `clang` to a different date.

#### Question

What are some software/libraries (implemented in any language) which can parse C code and which provide an API so I can build applications on top of them. I looked around, but I could not locate any free parsers.

The platforms I can use are anything on Windows or Mac or Linux, and any parsers written in  C/C++/Java/Perl/Python/PHP will work.

Comment: Its a little unclear if you want a parser (for some unspecified language) which is implemented in "C/C++" with a documented AST API, or you want a parser (in any language) which can process "C/C++" (the latter being a nonsequiter, because C and C++ are really very different languages).  Can you clarify?

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/17393852/120163  for a C++ parser that provides ASTs as XML.   That same parser also has a complete API to manipulating trees.

Comment: (Previous comment written when the question asked about both C and C++) The link shows a C++ parser, but there is a corresponding C parser.  The underlying engine has not only an interface for directly manipulation of AST nodes, but also has built-in support for source-to-source transformation using rewriting rules written using the target language (in this case, C) surface syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You could try one of the available grammars for [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/). ANTLR has support for creating tree walkers and you can walk/manipulate the AST manually if necessary. [ANTLR V3](http://www.antlr3.org/) has [several grammars](http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/list.html) available including a C preprocessor, [ANSI C](http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/1153358328744/C.g) and GNU C.

Comment: It seems like a good tool. I look for more before I use this as I am a little inexperienced in Java.

Comment: ANTLR can generate a parser in several languages although it is sometimes dependent on the grammar since they can contain support code. The ANSI C grammar I linked to contains very little Java code and can easily be ported to generate a lexer and parser in C or even C# if you so choose.