# Retrieving AST from C++ code in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there any way to generate AST from C++ code using Microsoft Visual Studio compiler?

I think about something similar to `-ast-dump` option from clang.

Comment: No, MSVC doesn't actually produce an AST during compilation.

Comment: It does, but it consumes it during compilation.  There was work on it a while back according to this post from 2007: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2007/08/17/visual-c-code-model.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe MSVC produces an AST you can access.

You can get ASTs for MSVC from our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html).  See this [DMS-generated example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17393852/120163) of a C++ AST.