# Is there any tool to visualize parsed tree for jtb & javacc like antlrworks

Tags: antlr, javacc, antlrworks

Antlrworks provides a visualized parsed tree for the input source code file. I was wondering if there is any equavalent tool for javacc & jtb
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Walk the tree.  Spit out nodes and arcs in [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org) ("dot") format.  Invoke graphviz on the result.

This won't be very useful for more than a hundred nodes, because it isn't very dense.

Remarkably, a more scalable way to is print a nested [S-expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression), in the following format:

```
<depth_from_root*spaces> ( <nodetype>  <newline>
        <childnode1_as_S-expression>
        <childnode2_as_S-expression>
        ...
        <childnodeN_as_S-expression>
               )<nodetype>
```

This in effect prints the tree sideways, e.g., with the root
at the left and children to the right.  You can print out very
big trees this way, and still be able to read them (if you
can scroll up and down through the text).

As an example:  for   a*(b+c)-d:

```
   (-
        (* 
           (+ 
              (variable b)
              (variable c)
            )+
         )*
         (constant 1)
    )-
```

This is also easily done with a tree walk.  You can easily make the printed
version more dense, or add more information.

See examples of both of these, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17393852/120163).

Comment: I think this is a kind of ast, not parsed tree

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is an AST or a parse tree; this technique works just fine.

Comment: Yep, I agree. Is there any tool/plugin to visualize based on JavaCC & JTB grammar? In the case developing from scratch,  graphviz is a good option. Thank you so much for your recommendation

Comment: The point is that both of these solutions are really easy to implement.

Comment: Thanks. This will be an answer if there is no tool/plugin available