# Does Roslyn Support C++ for generating syntax trees

Tags: c++, abstract-syntax-tree, roslyn

I have used Roslyn to create syntax trees for C# and Vb files.
Now I have to create syntax tree for a C++ file. I am not sure if Roslyn can help me here.

So my question is Does Roslyn support C++?

If Not then any other reference for the same?

I have found this ref. http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX.html
but it will be great if Roslyn can help me here.

Thanks

Comment: Roslyn doesn't support C++, so you can use [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/index.html) or something else for analyzing C++ code.

Comment: For C++ ASTs, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17393852/120163

Answer (score 0):

Roslyn is only C# and VB.net compiler as a service. There is an extension for F#, and I don't know if there is any for c++/cli. If you are looking only for C++, but not for the C++/CLI then libclang should perform well here.