# How to visualize an Abstract Syntax Tree graphically?

Tags: c++, abstract-syntax-tree, graph-visualization

I wrote a simple compiler in C++ and want to visualize the Abstract Syntax Tree it produces. Currently, I dump the AST in a super long string similar to something below:

`Program(decls=[ConstDecl(type=BasicTypeKind::Int, value=Num(n=1, loc=Location(1, 21)), name=positive, loc=Location(1, 10)), ConstDecl(type=BasicTypeKind::Int, value=Num(n=-1, loc=Location(2, 21)), name=negative, loc=Location(2, 10)), ConstDecl(type=BasicTypeKind::Int, value=Num(n=100, loc=Location(3, 26)), name=max_heap_size, loc=Location(3, 10)), ConstDecl(type=BasicTypeKind::Character, value=Char(c=99, loc=Location(4, 23)), name=...`

As you can see, this dump isn't very human friendly in terms of visualization. One cannot naturally relate the notion a **tree** to such a long string. I tried the approach to pretty-print the AST and found [astpretty](https://github.com/asottile/astpretty), which is for Python. It aims a lot in debugging but what if I want an illustration of the AST? A graphical format surely fits better.

Actually I have the picture about what the output I am looking forward. `Graphviz` does a great job on this field and various graphs the C++ document tool `Doxygen` generates are very close to my purpose conceptually.

Putting these together, I want a way to turn an AST in memory as C++ objects into decent graphic output (static one is ok). Any good starting point?

**Edit:** as comments said, dumping my AST in format `Graphviz` recognizes is a good starting point. I will try do it this way until new and more concrete problems arise. Thanks guys.

Comment: Why not simply add newlines, plus some indent, after `(`, `[`, between array elements, etc. in your output? Should have looked much better afterwards.

Comment: Use dot format such that graphviz will be able to draw it correctly

Comment: It seems to me you have a proper starting point already. Translate your AST representation to graphviz format and render from there. Unless, of course, there is something more to this question, in case which I suggest you edit your post.

Comment: @bipll I already has a pretty-printer, though in Python. A png will do better than plain text, as I hold it.

Comment: This SO answer shows what you can produce if you a) print your AST as nested tree with indentation, and b) if you walk your AST and spit out GraphVis ("dot") commands for the nodes and arcs.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17393852/120163

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that is both fast and acceptable. LLVM-8 includes an option to visualize a Control Flow Graph (CFG) by generating a dot format file from it. Basically this works for more general graph structures as long as you specialize the `llvm::GraphTraits` and `llvm::DOTGraphTraits` templates (with a little work around) and the `llvm::WriteGraph()` will work for you. Here is result without too much fine-tuning:

[image]

given the C-like snippet:

```
const int IntConstant = 1;
int Array[2];

void main() {
  Printf("hello");
}
```

This language is a simplification of C and it is case-insensitive. A `Printf()` is represented by a `Write` statement as the node in the image. `ConstDecl` means *constant declaration*. `VarDecl` means *variable declaration* and `FuncDef` means *function definition*. Other things are pretty much straightforward.

Before explaining the magic, I would like to point you to these documents that really help how to use the llvm APT involved.

- [GraphTraits](http://llvm.org/doxygen/GraphTraits_8h_source.html) to know the signature your code should have.
- [WriteGraph](http://llvm.org/doxygen/GraphWriter_8h_source.html) to know what `WriteGraph` requires of your code.
- [CFGPrinter](http://llvm.org/doxygen/CFGPrinter_8h_source.html) to know how to specialize your `GraphTraits`
- [DOTGraphTraits](http://llvm.org/doxygen/DOTGraphTraits_8h_source.html) to know how to make your illustration meaningful by giving labels and descriptions to nodes.
- [iterator_facade_base](http://llvm.org/doxygen/iterator_8h_source.html) to know how to painlessly write working iterators.

Now with this knowledge bases, you just need to put them together. In fact, follow these steps:

1. think of how to iterate over each node in the AST and specialize the `nodes_iterator` implementation.
2. think of how to iterate over all children of a given node and specialize the `ChildIteratorType` implementation.
3. think of how to extract useful information from your nodes and specialize the `getNodeLabel()` and `getNodeDescription()` of your `DOTGraphTraits`.
4. note the mine: the `NodeRef` type of `GraphTraits` **must** be a pointer! knowing this beforehand can save you a day. This is true for the latest version. Maybe in the future they will remove the restriction.

My current implementation only include the class name of a node as its label and a self-explanatory string as its description without any fine-tuning. If you want more effects, i.e., color, shape, etc., you can do it in your `DOTGraphTraits`.